# Vertex shader animation is rotating with camera

Tags: glsl, processing, shader

I am new to shaders, and I want to animate an object with the vertex shader.

Right now I just want to move it with a constant. For some reason, instead of going in the x-direction of the world, it moves in the x-direction of the camera. (So whenever I turn the camera, the object rotates with me)

The project is in processing, but I don't think it affects the shader.

THE PROCESSING CODE:

```
PShader sdr;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000, P3D);
  noStroke();
  sdr = loadShader("shdFrag.glsl", "shdVert.glsl");
}

void draw() {

  background(200);

  // Set camera
  camera(0, -300, 700, mouseX-500, 0, 200, 0, 1, 0);

  // Ground
  resetShader();
  beginShape();
  fill(100);
  vertex(-500, 0,  500);
  vertex( 500, 0,  500);
  vertex( 500, 0, -500);
  vertex(-500, 0, -500);
  endShape();

  // Red Sphere
  shader(sdr);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  sphere(100);
}
```

VERTEX SHADER:

```
uniform mat4 transform;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;
out vec4 vertColor;

void main() {
  vec4 pos = position;
  pos.x  += 300;


  vertColor = color;
  gl_Position = transform * pos;
}
```

FRAGMENT SHADER:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

in vec4 vertColor;

void main() {
  vec4 color = vertColor;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(color.xyz, 1);
}
```

A GIF of what is happening:
[the scene with a sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgXrO.gif)

Comment: can you create a gif of what you mean by "rotates with me"?

Comment: If the code is in Processing, please show _that_ code as [mcve], because the Processing API does not support OpenGL syntax (even if the JVM that your sketch run in has a way for you to write shader code - that's no longer really Processing, but just Java) so what you're showing now is guaranteed not the code you're actually using. Unless you're using additional things that you forgot to put in your post, in which case: talk about those in your post.